# An inequality with a prime number

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers, contest-math

I have this to purpose :

> Let $a,b,c$ be real positive numbers such that $abc=1$ prove that :
>   $$\frac{a^2}{(a^{11}+1)^2}+\frac{b^2}{(b^{11}+1)^2}+\frac{c^2}{(c^{11}+1)^2}\leq \frac{10^7}{9193531}$$

Where $9193531$ is a prime number wich makes the problem harder .

Really I have no ideas to prove this and all my classical methods fails automatically when I want solve this problem .

Furthermore I do not know which class of functions belongs $f(x)$ where :

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{(x^{11}+1)^2}$$

Maybe we can find a way with the concept of [Quasiconvex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function)

If you have any hints it would be nice.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why primality makes it harder..

Comment: I fed it to [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize++x%5E2%2F(x%5E11%2B1)%5E2+%2B+y%5E2%2F(y%5E11%2B1)%5E2%2Bz%5E2%2F(z%5E11%2B1)%5E2+subject+to+xyz%3D1) and the limit is very tight.  It found a maximum of $1.08772$ at about $(1.51865, 0.811465, 0.811465)$  The right side is about  $1.08772136$

Comment: Have you tried Lagrange multipliers? That's usually the method to find extreme values of functions under constraints, though it can be quite tedious..

Comment: @user496634 I used Lagrange multipliers in my answer to show that the smaller two values are the same.

Comment: @max8128 Do you know where this question is from?

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{(x^{11}+1)^2}.$$
By a compactness argument, there exists a triple $(a,b,c)$ of positive real numbers that maximizes the sum $f(a)+f(b)+f(c)$ subject to the constraint $abc=1$.
We may assume that $0<a\leq b\leq c$.
Then $a\leq1$ and $c\geq1$.
If $a<10^{-1/11}$ then increasing $a$ and decreasing $c$ contradicts the maximality of $(a,b,c)$.
Thus, $a\geq10^{-1/11}$.
If $b>1$ then
$$f(a)+f(b)+f(c)\leq f(10^{-1/11})+f(1)+f(1)\leq1.044$$
which contradicts the maximality of $(a,b,c)$ (there are better solutions than $1.044$).
Thus, $b\leq1$.
In summary,
$$10^{-1/11}\leq a\leq b\leq1\leq c.$$
By Lagrange multipliers,
$$\left\langle f^\prime(a),f^\prime(b),f^\prime(c)\right\rangle=\lambda\left\langle bc,ac,ab\right\rangle=\lambda\left\langle\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b},\frac{1}{c}\right\rangle.$$
If we set $p(x)=xf^\prime(x)$ then $p(a)=p(b)=p(c)$.
Since $a\leq b\leq1$, looking at the graph of $p(x)$ shows that $a=b$.
Then we wish to maximize the one-variable function
$$g(x)=2f(x)+f\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=2\left(\frac{x}{x^{11}+1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{x^{20}}{x^{22}+1}\right)^2.$$
The maximum occurs slightly above $x=10^{-1/11}$.
We can find the maximum by setting $g^\prime(x)=0$.
We can compute
$$g^\prime(x)=\frac{4x(1-10x^{11})}{(x^{11}+1)^3}+\frac{4x^{39}(10-x^{22})}{(x^{22}+1)^3}.$$
Setting $g^\prime(x)=0$ gives
$$\frac{1-10x^{11}}{(x^{11}+1)^3}+\frac{x^{38}(10-x^{22})}{(x^{22}+1)^3}=0.$$
Clearing denominators gives
$$(1-10x^{11})(x^{22}+1)^3+x^{38}(10-x^{22})(x^{11}+1)^3=0.$$
The root of this polynomial can be found to arbitrary precision using Newton's method:
$$x\approx0.8114699441003698687884808010408458056245.$$
Then
$$g(x)\approx1.0877212680663091337501932514101994261908490$$
which is about $0.0000000873$ below $10^7/9193531$.

To make this 100% rigorous, you need to use bounds on $g^\prime(x)$ (this is rather tedious and was done in an earlier version of this answer).

Answer (score 1):

#### Geometric Explanation "min/max at x=y"

(Not an Answer) 
  
 
  
 
Using $c=1/(ab)$, Let $a=x$, $b=y$ and define:
$$ 
\begin{align} 
&f(x,y)=\frac{10^7}{9193531}-\frac{x^{2}}{\left(x^{11}+1\right)^2}-\frac{y^{2}}{\left(y^{11}+1\right)^2}-\frac{(xy)^{20}}{\left((xy)^{11}+1\right)^2}=f(y,x) \\ 
&f({\small-\frac{8}{10}},{\small-\frac{9}{10}})\approx-1.4\lt0, \quad f({\small2},{\small2})\approx+1.0\gt0 
\end{align} 
$$

Benefiting from the function symmetric behavior $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$, the inequality holds for ***the special case*** min/max accord at $x=y$. Thus, re-define: 
$$ 
\begin{align} 
&f(x)=\frac{10^7}{9193531}-\frac{2x^{2}}{\left(x^{11}+1\right)^2}-\frac{x^{40}}{\left(x^{22}+1\right)^2} \\ 
&\qquad=\color{blue}{\frac{10^7}{9193531}-\frac{2x^{2}+4x^{24}+x^{40}+2x^{46}+2x^{51}+x^{62}}{1+2x^{11}+3x^{22}+4x^{33}+3x^{44}+2x^{55}+x^{66}}} 
\end{align} 
$$ 
And the question now turns to be about $\,{\small f(x)}\,$ roots for $\,{\small x\gt0}\,$.
  
 
[image]
  
 
  
 
Putting $\,{\small f(x)=0}\,$ and simplifying, gives the equivalent polynomial: 
$$ 
\begin{align} 
p(x)=\,&\,\color{red}{{10^7}\left({1+2x^{11}+3x^{22}+4x^{33}+3x^{44}+2x^{55}+x^{66}}\right)} \\ 
&\,\color{red}{-{9193531}\left(2x^{2}+4x^{24}+x^{40}+2x^{46}+2x^{51}+x^{62}\right)} 
\end{align} 
$$ 
Because the polynomial degree is high, and to determine if $\,{\small p(x)}\,$ has any $\,{\color{red}{\small\text{real root}}}\,$ for $\,{\small x\gt0}\,$, it is enough to use [Sturm theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) to compare number of roots inside the two regions $\,{\small [-1,0]}\,$ and $\,{\small [-1,\infty)}\,$, which should result in only $\,{\color{red}{\small\text{ONE}}}\,$ root in both, hence $\,{\small p(x)\ne0\,\,\colon\,x\in(0,\infty)}\,$. 
  
 
[image]

Comment: Why is it $(xy)^{20}$ in the definition of $f(x,y)$?

Comment: Also, why does $f(x_0,y_0)=f(y_0,x_0)=0$ imply that $x_0=y_0$?

Comment: @ThomasBrowning : $(xy)^{20}$ appears after simplifying: $$ f(x,y)=\frac{10^7}{9193531}-\frac{x^{2}}{\left(x^{11}+1\right)^2}-\frac{y^{2}}{\left(y^{11}+1\right)^2}-\frac{\left(\frac{1}{xy}\right)^2}{\left(\left(\frac{1}{xy}\right)^{11}+1\right)^2} $$ Your second comment is correct (Thank you!). Indeed $f(x_0,y_0)=f(y_0,x_0)=0$ don't imply $x_0=y_0$ (I shall edit this). I'll mark my answer as a geometry explanation of the special case $x=y$. On the other hand, I still believe the min/max of $f(x,y)$ shall occurred at $x=y$ though I don't know how to show this. Thanks again.